# Converting Message to HttpRequestMessage object causes this failure "Expecting element 'Stream' from namespace"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization, httprequest

I am using the following method to convert Message object to HttpRequestMessage

```
HttpRequestMessage shadowRequestMessage = Message.ToHttpRequestMessage();
```

Implementation of extension method could be found in the link below and it is provided by .NET framework

[MessageExtensionMethods](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Channels/System/ServiceModel/Channels/MessageExtensionMethods.cs,b2df92fe58a01387,references) ToHttpRequestMessage method

When i call `ToHttpRequestMessage` method it gives me the following exception

```
{"Expecting element 'Stream' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'SayHello', namespace 'http://tempuri.org/'. "}
```

This was the Message object value :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://localhost:38405/OriginalService.svc</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IOriginalService/SayHello</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>... stream ...</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Failure Stacktrace :

```
 at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.GetBodyCore[T](XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageExtensionMethods.CreateMessageContent(Message message, Boolean suppressEntityBody)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageExtensionMethods.CreateRequestMessage(Message message, HttpRequestMessageProperty requestMessageProperty)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageExtensionMethods.ToHttpRequestMessage(Message message)
```

This is the sample application :

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IOriginalService
{
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello();
}

public class OriginalServiceSvc : IOriginalService
{
       public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
}
```

Can someone explain me how can i fix this issue?

Comment: You need to provide the code that is throwing the exception, your service implementation is fairly irrelevant.

Comment: @CodingGorilla This method is causing the issue : HttpRequestMessage shadowRequestMessage = Message.ToHttpRequestMessage(); This extension method is provided by .NET library http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Channels/System/ServiceModel/Channels/MessageExtensionMethods.cs,b2df92fe58a01387,references . I have added this information to the question as well. Let me know if i am missing anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That method ([MessageExtensionMethods.ToHttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageextensionmethods.tohttprequestmessage)) cannot be used to convert any arbitrary [Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message) instances to a [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage). It can only be used for a specific message type (that is created by based on a byte array). Unfortunately the documentation for that method doesn't specify this limitation, which can lead to issues like yours.

If you want to convert arbitrary WCF messages into [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage) instances, you would need a [MessageEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder), which is the WCF component responsible for converting the WCF message body (which internally is represented by a XML Infoset, but whose contents after encoded don't necessarily need to be XML) into bytes (which you could use to create the [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage)).